# Check error before submit

Tags: powerapps

Currently, I have a button in my form with action (generate title for the document, change some fields values, write histories...) and then SubmitForm(MyForm).

But, I have three required fields, and if they are empty, my SubmitForm generate errors. What I need, is to check these fieds before submit.
I can use IfBlank, but in this case, I don't have the error named below my fields.
How can I do the same check than the submitform, before to submit my forms ?

Thanks !

Comment: If the button will be disabled when some required fields are empty will be enough?

Comment: It could be enough, if it's possible to see the red warning "Fields should'nt be empty". It it possible ? When I submit and have these errors, if I put a number in my field, warning disapear, and if I delete the number, warning appears again. Is it possible to have this warning if my default number (0) is suppress ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataCardValue1, DataCardValue2, DataCardValue3 - your required fields

To disable button:
**Button *DisplayMode*** : `If(IsBlank(DataCardValue1.Text) || IsBlank(DataCardValue2.Text) || IsBlank(DataCardValue3.Text), DisplayMode.Disabled, DisplayMode.Edit)`

To display warning when fields are empty:

**DataCardValue1,2,3** ***Fill*** : `If(IsBlank(DataCardValue1.Text), RGBA(220, 72, 80, 1),RGBA(255, 255, 255, 1))`
**DataCardValue1,2,3 *HintText*** : `If(IsBlank(DataCardValue1.Text), "field shouldn't be empty" ,"")`

Comment: This is not exactly what I thought, but it works fine ! Thanks a lot !

Comment: One more question : is it possible to change the hint text color ?

Comment: Sure, you can do it in Fill property, just change RGBA(220, 72, 80, 1) values or instead of RGBA use 'Color.NameOfColor' or ColorValue(#ffffff). You can read about this there: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-colors

Comment: I already did this, but to change the background color. The hint text is still grey. Normal text is black.

Comment: I think you can't change color of the hint text. You can remove HintText value, add a text Label - adjust it on your DataCardValue, Text property = your hint text, Visible property:  `If(IsBlank(DataCardValue1.Text), true, false)`. In Label property you can change the text color.

Comment: Right. Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

You can use IsBlank for checking that is the text field is blank or not and on its true you can use Notify("Please Fill Required Fields",Warning) this will show an error message. Notify has Success and Alert notification types, Check it out.